# Why is iterating through the outer dimension with an outer loop faster than with an inner loop?

Tags: performance, caching, memory, ram

Let's consider a matrix

```
std::vector<std::vector<int>> matrix;
```

where each row has the same length. I will call each `std::vector<int>` a column.

**Why is iterating through the outer dimension with an outer loop faster than with an inner loop?**

First program: Iterating through columns first

```
int sum = 0;
for (int col = 0 ; col < matrix.size() ; col++)
{
   for (int row = 0 ; row < matrix[0].size() ; row++)
   {
      sum += matrix[col][row];
   }
}
```

Second program: Iterating through rows first

```
int sum = 0;
for (int row = 0 ; row < matrix[0].size() ; row++) // Assuming there is at least one element in matrix
{
   for (int col = 0 ; col < matrix.size() ; col++)
   {
      sum += matrix[col][row];
   }
}
```

Here are my guesses

**Jumping around the memory**

I could have a vague intuition that jumping around in the memory would take more time than reading the memory that is contiguous but I thought memory access of the RAM takes constant time. Plus, there are no moving part in the DRAM and I don't understand why it would be faster to read two `int`s if they are continuous?

**Bus width**

An `int` take either 2 bytes (although it may vary depending on the data model). In a machine with a 8 byte wide bus, I can imagine that eventually if the `int`s are contiguous in memory, then 4 `int`s (depending on the data model) could be sent to the processor at every clock cycle, while only one `int` could be sent per clock cycle if they are not contiguous.

If this is the case, then if the `matrix` would contain `long long int` which are 8 byte long, we would not see any difference between the two programs anymore (I haven't tested it).

**Cache**

I am not sure why, but I feel like the cache could be the reason for why the second program is slower. The effect with the cache might be related to the bus size argument I talked about just above. It is possible that only memory that is contiguous in the DRAM could load in the cache but I don't know why it would be the case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yeah, it's [cache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU_cache).

There's a strange coincidence<sup>1</sup> that when programs access data in memory, they often access nearby data immediately or shortly after.

CPU designers realized this and thus design caches to load a whole chunk of memory at once.

So when you access `matrix[0][0]`, much, if not all of the rest of `matrix[0]` was pulled into cache along with the single element at `matrix[0][0]`, whereas there's a good chance that nothing from `matrix[20]` made it into cache.

Note that this is dependent on your matrix consisting of contiguous arrays, at least at the last dimension. If you were using, say linked lists, you would probably<sup>2</sup> not see much difference, instead experience the slower performance regardless of access order.

The reason is that cache loads contiguous blocks. Consider if `matrix[0][0]` refers to the memory address `0x12340000`. Accessing that would load that byte, plus the next 127 bytes into cache (exact amount depends on the cpu). So you'd have every byte from `0x12340000` to `0x1234007F` in cache.

In a contiguous array, your next element at `0x12340004` is already in cache. But linked lists aren't contiguous, the next element could be virtually anywhere. If it's outside of that `0x12340000` to `0x1234007F` range, you haven't gained anything.

---

<sup>1</sup> It's really not that strange of a coincidence if you think about it. Using local stack variables? Accesses to the same area of memory. Iterating across a 1-dimensional array? Lots of accesses to the same area of memory. Iterating across a 2-dimensional array with the outer dimension in the outer loop and the inner arrays in the inner, nested loop? Basically iterating over a bunch of 1-dimensional arrays.

<sup>2</sup> It's possibly you might luck out and have your linked list's nodes all right next to each other, but that seems like a very unlikely scenario. And you'll still won't fit as many elements in cache because the pointers to the next element takes up space, and there will be an additional, small performance hit from the indirection.

Comment: Computer Scientists even sometimes analyze algorithms with respect to this factor, they call it **I/O-efficiency** (or sometimes Cache-efficiency).

Comment: @8bittree Thank you! I am not sure I understand why non-continguous memory won't load in the cache like continguous memory does?

Comment: It actually depends. Sometimes arrays are stored with continuous rows and some other times with continuous columns, so cycling through rows might not always be faster

Comment: @Alex Sure I understand that what I called row and column in my post is arbitrary.

Comment: @Remi.b Great. Just to make sure everyone gets this detail :)

Comment: @Remi.b The main reason behind that is because for your hard drive (also for SSDs) the operation to go to an **arbitrary position** (random access) is a **very expensive operation**. It takes extremely long (compared to other operations). However, once at that position, reading the **next bytes around** is **extremely fast** in comparison. Because of that the processor decides, once it is already there, to also directly load a bunch of other bytes around because in many applications they will be relevant in the near future.

Comment: @Remi.b Just to give you a rough overview of the dimensions: The **seek time** for HDD is about **5ms** and for SSD around **0.1ms** whereas the **transfer rate** (reading the bytes around) is about **50 MB/s** for HDD (roughly 20ns per byte) and **200 MB/s** for SSD.

Comment: @Remi.b I added a couple paragraphs to expand on why contiguity is important. Does that help?

Answer (score -1):

When Going Column - row, you are counting like so ([C][R]) [0][0] + [0][1] + [0][2] ... and so on. So you are not switching between the elements of the array.

When going row - column, you are counting like so ([C][R]) [0][0] + [1][0] + [2][0] This way you are switching between the elements of the array each time, so in DRAM it takes longer.

2D Arrays are handled like so : new Array{array1, array2, array3}; Arrays inside of an array. Counting down an array (C-R) is faster than Switching arrays and counting the element in the same row (R-C).

Arrays are a sectioned off piece of memory so when you have 2D arrays and you count (R-C) you are jumping around in the DRAM which is slower.

It does not matter that there are no mechanical parts in DRAM, jumping around will be slower. Example: SRAM has no mechanical parts but is slower than DRAM (with larger size of course) because more distance has the be traveled do to the larger size of the extra transistors and capacitors.

**edit** after reading the other answer, I would like to include that when you iterate (C-R) the whole element can be loaded into cache for quick access. But when going (R-C) loading a new array element into cache each time is not efficient or possibly does not happen due to inefficiency.

Comment: I was not able to comment on the question due to reputation. So here I want to say that is a very good question, but have you done tests to check this out? what were the results? I would like to know how much slower it is.

Comment: This is the exact opposite of the meaning of RAM: RANDOM access memory. Every single place has the same access time. As the other answer says, it has to do with cache, specifically, if the cpu is caching rows or columns.

Comment: @Alex DRAM has a variable access times due to a memory hierarchy, which is counterintuitive to its name.